# Is there a way to use Angular Material without the styling?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, material-design

My company currently uses Angular Material to style inputs, buttons and etc. We're moving to a different style but Id still like to use the fancy components like Datepicker, Prefix, Suffix, and alike.

Is there a way to use material components with our own custom style?

Attached is a picture of the Datepicker vs our new style. We'd like the datepicker to take on our new style, getting rid of all the Material styling.

[image]

Here is an example of the different types of html:

```
//Material Input
            <mat-form-field floatLabel="always" class="dynamic-input" *ngIf="answer.isInput && !answer.isConditional">
                <span matPrefix *ngIf="answer.hasPrefix">{{answer.prefixText}}</span>
                <input matInput (blur)="answer.fireNewLead === true ? onTriggerNewLead() : null" [placeholder]="answer.placeholderText" [name]="answer.propertyKey" [ngModel]="object[answer.propertyKey]" (ngModelChange)="object[answer.propertyKey]=$event" type="text">
                <span matSuffix *ngIf="answer.hasSuffix">{{answer.suffixText}}</span>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field floatLabel="always" class="dynamic-input" *ngIf="answer.isInput && answer.isConditional && returnConditionIsTrue(answer)">
                <span matPrefix *ngIf="answer.hasSuffix">{{answer.prefixText}}</span>
                <input matInput (blur)="answer.fireNewLead === true ? onTriggerNewLead() : null;" [placeholder]="answer.placeholderText" [name]="answer.propertyKey" [ngModel]="object[answer.propertyKey]" (ngModelChange)="object[answer.propertyKey]=$event" type="text">
                <span matSuffix *ngIf="answer.hasSuffix">{{answer.suffixText}}</span>
            </mat-form-field>

//Our Input
            <div class="input-wrapper" *ngIf="answer.isInput" [style.width]="((answer.width/100) * 50) + 'rem'">
                <input type="text" (blur)="answer.fireNewLead === true ? onTriggerNewLead() : null" [placeholder]="answer.placeholderText" [name]="answer.id" [(ngModel)]="responses[returnResponseIndex(answer)].value"  class="input-box normal-input-box" *ngIf="!answer.isConditional && !answer.isAddressSearch && !answer.isVehicleVIN">
                <input type="text" (blur)="answer.fireNewLead === true ? onTriggerNewLead() : null" [placeholder]="answer.placeholderText" [name]="answer.id" [(ngModel)]="responses[returnResponseIndex(answer)].value"  class="input-box normal-input-box" *ngIf="answer.isConditional && !answer.isAddressSearch && !answer.isVehicleVIN && returnConditionTrue(answer.conditionAnswerId ? returnResponseValue(responses[returnConditionResponseIndex(answer.conditionAnswerId)]) : null, answer.conditionValue)">
            </div>
```

Comment: The answer to the titular question is yes. To do so, you'll need to understand the "C" in CSS, namely, how the cascade and specificity works. Explaining that would take more room than SO allows for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add styles to classes that Angular Material uses (check them with inspect on chrome browser) in your styles.scss or in any other global styles file you have.

If you want to change them in each component you can create a parent class, and then penetrate the angular material classes using `::ng-deep .my-class .mat-button .mat-button-wrapper {...}`

good luck! it's a lot of trial and error, but doable!

note: be aware that the styles that are applied are those with 'more' selectors... so if you see `.mat-button.mat-primary .mat-button-wrapper {}` in your inspect, don't simply try to override the `.mat-button-wrapper` because it doesn't have enough specificity, you need to use the specificity of material plus your own to override the one in place.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about this but was hoping for an alternative. It'd be nice if Angular Material had a way to reset styling. I like the options provided to each input and button but the styling isn't fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Although *possible* as others have indicated, as a development effort this is likely to take more effort and be more prone to problems than simply moving to something else. It would be extremely difficult to provide sufficient test coverage that might ensure you've done *everything* properly, so that something doesn't suddenly rear its ugly head in production.

If you really want to do this, create your own fork of the @angular/material project (or simply steal the source code), and rewrite all of the style code to suit your needs.